# The relationship between uniform distribution and $\mathbb E[\log X]$

Tags: random-variables, logarithms, expected-value

I'm trying to understand a proof which uses the trick that if $W_t\sim U(0, F(t))$ has a uniform distribution where $F$ is cdf for a random variable $X$, then

$$\mathbb E[\log X|X\leq t]=\mathbb E[\log(F^{-1}(W_t))]$$

I believe $F^{-1}(W_t)\sim F$ in $[0,F(t)]$, and $$\mathbb E[\log X|X\leq t]=\frac{\mathbb E[\log X *1_{X\leq t}]}{P(X\leq t)}=\frac{1}{F(t)}\mathbb E[\log X*1_{X\leq t}]$$ but can't combine them together. Thanks in advance for any help to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that
$$
\log(F^{-1}(W_t))\sim\log X\mid X\le t
$$
for $t>0$. For $x\le\log t$,
\begin{align*}
P(\log(F^{-1}(W_t))\le x)
&=P(F^{-1}(W_t)\le\exp(x))\\
&=P(W_t\le F(\exp(x)))\\
&=\frac{F(\exp(x))}{F(t)}\\
&=\frac{P(X\le\exp(x))}{P(X\le t)}\\
&=\frac{P(\log X\le x)}{P(X\le t)}\\
&=\frac{P(\log X\le x, X\le t)}{P(X\le t)}\\
&=P(\log X\le x\mid X\le t).
\end{align*}
Since $\log(F^{-1}(W_t))$ has the same distribution as $\log X\mid X\le t$, their expected values are equal.

I hope this helps.